# How can it be legal for companies to send me random crap and then demand payment?

Tags: internet, harassment, sweden, postal-service

(Although I live in Sweden, I think this applies more or less globally.)

Numerous times throughout the years, the most recently today, I have received snailmail notifications from the postal office saying that I have a package to collect. These are not fake messages; somebody has actually inputted my address information (available in public, obviously) on random websites to send me items I don't want.

They never state any e-mail address or web address on the notification, but it does say the company name. I'm thus forced to manually search and attempt to find this company's website and then figure out how to contact them through some form, then waste tons of time writing them an explanation and hoping that they don't ignore me.

Before you tell me to "stop pissing off people", I have to tell you that I do not control the actions of other human beings. (It's highly questionable if I even control *my own* actions...)

To me, it's unthinkable to expect something to be delivered which I haven't pre-paid. The idea of this being possible at all is insane to me. And it's clearly abused, wasting tons of time and energy and causing stress as I have to repeatedly deal with this nonsense.

If the person sending stuff to my address, in my name, had been forced to pre-pay it, it wouldn't matter if it sits on the postal office shelves until it expires and they throw it away. However, since they don't have to pre-pay, the company assumes that I actually ordered it just because it's my name and address (again, public information that any psychopath anywhere in the world can look up in one second), and treats me as a "misbehaving customer" for not paying for "my" goods.

Even though I had nothing whatsoever to do with the order and never have even heard of their business.

How can this be legal? It's almost as if they *designed* this in order to allow for abuse... Especially as there is no obvious/direct way to dispute it on the "reminder" notice.

Comment: It's not all that different from ordering pizza or other food delivery. Assuming these are legit businesses, I'm surprised some still accept COD orders though.

Answer (score 1):

### It isn’t legal

If people want to send you stuff, they are free to do so. You don’t have to pay for it.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking it is legal to send stuff, and it is legal to nicely ask for money - you just don't have to comply. However, if the sender (wrongly) claims you are required to pay, that might count as fraud.

Comment: @sleske true enough - the OP did say “demand” so that’s what I addressed